# Как получить url предыдущей странице на python через QWebEngineHistory?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Пытаюсь получить url предыдущей страницы в браузере QWebEngineView, таким кодом

```py
            self.browser = QWebEngineView()
            self.history_back = QWebEngineHistory(self.browser)
            self.url_start = self.history_back.backItem()
            print(self.url_start)
```

И бьёт такую ошибку:

```
    self.history_back = QWebEngineHistory(self.browser)
TypeError: PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineHistory cannot be instantiated or sub-classed
```

Как правильно получить url предыдущей странице?
Помогите разобраться. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У [QWebEngineHistory](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginehistory.html) приватный конструктор, т.к. тот существует только в контексте браузера, поэтому [обращатесь к нему](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#history) через [QWebEngineView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html):

```
self.browser = QWebEngineView()
...
self.url_start = self.browser.history().backItem()
print(self.url_start)
print(self.url_start.url())
```